# Laravel 5.4 Route back in blade

Tags: laravel

I need button back to page previous in blade
I try

`{{ route(back()) }} Not working`

`{{back()}} Not working`

`{{ redirect(back()) }} Not working`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use the previous method

```
{{ URL::previous() }}
```

Or you can also use helpers.

```
// Get the current URL without the query string...
echo url()->current();

// Get the current URL including the query string...
echo url()->full();

// Get the full URL for the previous request...
echo url()->previous();
```